# PHP iconv not working as expected

Tags: php, iconv

I have an array of strings. I would like to separate these strings into a multidimensional array, based on the first character of the string. This is the code I am using:

```
$sorted = [];
foreach ($allStrings AS $string)
{
    $section = strtoupper(iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string)[0]);
    $sorted[$section][] = $string;
}
```

The problem I am having is one of my pages if called `é Test`.

Instead of converting the section to  `e`, it converts it to `?`

Comment: This is why non-native english are better dev. Your issue will be identical with unicodes composed of two ansi blocks. This is a fairly complex problem. Good luck!

Comment: this is just a shot in the dark: try to manually pre-convert `$string` with `$newString = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8');`. Maybe it isn't UTF-8?

Comment: or check first if $string _IS_ UTF-8 via `mb_detect_encoding($string)`